# Header says UTF-8 but accents not showing up properly - why? (php)

Tags: php, html, encoding, utf-8

I abstracted the header from a larger set of php files for clarity.  When I load it into Wampserver, the `<p>é</p>` appears as � on the site, despite the header calling for utf-8 charset.  What is wrong in this document?

(Note that I tried to modify the encoding by replacing iso-8859-1 with utf-8, that didn't help.)

**header.php:**

```
<?php
    header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>'
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr" lang="fr">
    <head>
        <title>Blabla</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>é</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you have utf-8 set in the editor in which you edit the file as well?

Comment: Is the file saved in the correct encoding? Have you tried to add the Content-Type meta element?

Comment: Why are you sending contradicting character set info? That can't work. It needs to be one or the other.

Comment: Remove XML version info.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are sending two contradicting character sets, `iso-8859-1` and `utf-8`.

If you

- fix that and send only one character set, and
- encode the actual file in the character set you specify (there should be a character set option in your IDE's or editor's "Save as..." dialog)

it should work.

Comment: @JDelage you're welcome. But do also fix the contradiction, it may give you problems in the long term

Comment: Yes, but I had tried it and it had not solved the problem, whereas encoding the actual PHP file in Notepad++ does solve things.

Answer (score 15):

try this`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>` in the head section

and also check your file encoding

Comment: Problem was the file encoding (it was ANSI), so this takes care of it.  Thanks!

Comment: Adding the following line in the html works for me: <meta charset="utf-8">.  NOTE: Make sure your text file encoding is Default (determined from content: Cp1252)

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me : 
I add to the MVC COntroller : produces={"application/json;charset=utf-8"}